# WCF Service Application and MVC4 Application hosted on local IIS (not express) throwing connection string erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework, iis

There are already a handful of questions out there but none seem to have gotten any attention or answers to what is causing this error, and how to fix it.

**Background**

I have created an ASP.NET MVC4 application that has a single point of data access in another application I created using the WCF Application project template in VS2012. If I run both applications in debug mode (so it is using IIS express at this point for both) they can talk to each other just fine. All my calls work, no issues.

I wanted to test it in a more realistic environment so I got my IIS set up (IIS 8 on a windows 8 box), created a website, and underneath that website I am hosting both these applications, the MVC one, which I am calling Dashboard, and the WCF one which I am calling Service. So it looks something like this in IIS

```
 MYMACHINENAME
 |
 --App Pools
 |Sites
     --local
        --aspnet_client
        --dashboard (application, MVC4)
        --service (application, WCF)
```

I can hit the localhost/service and I see the right information there, so I know it is hosting correctly.

I updated the service reference in the MVC4 project to point to localhost/service rather than the iis express one I was using.

**The Problem**

Adding the new service reference to the MVC4 app worked fine, I got the wsdl info and I can see all the endpoint calls I defined. After adding the new service reference, I re-published the 'dashboard' application. When I navigation to localhost/dashboard, I get an error deep inside the Reference.cs file that the service reference created.
Here is the code that is throwing the error:

```
MyServiceAPIClient svc = new MyServiceAPIClient();
svc.Open();
User userRecord = svc.GetUserRecord(adSAMName);
```

On that third line it gets into the Reference.cs file that is created when I add the service reference. This line of code it dies on in the Reference.cs file is here:

```
public Dashboard.Web.MyApiService.User GetUserRecord(string userName) {
    return base.Channel.GetUserRecord(userName);
}
```

And the error message is this:

```
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. 
This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. 
Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
```

There is no inner exception for me to look at, so I am at a loss here.

**The Question**

Should be pretty obvious what the question is here. Multiple questions really:

1. What could be causing this issue? Keep in mind it works fine in IIS express, just debugging both in VS2012.
2. Is this an issue with the configuration of my MVC app, WCF app, or IIS? A combination of them all?
3. How do I fix it??

There is a lot of code files and config files I can post here, but I wanted to keep it shorter for reading sake, if there is code that you would like to see here, let me know if the comments and I can post it.

**Update**

I did as advised and attached to the process running the service in IIS. Digging into the inner exceptions it seems to be an access/login issue with trying to hit the database.

I can't seem to get the connection string to work with a built in SQL user though, so I am scratching my head again.

This is the connection string I am trying:

```
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Server:.;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=SQLAuthUser;Password=yourmom;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I run the process again and it tells me login failed for that user I specified, and I am also getting this message that I have never seen before:

```
Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.
```

Halp!?

**Update: Solution**

So my connection string is now this:

```
<add name="NeumontDB" connectionString="Server=ServerName; Database=NeumontDB; User Id=Username; Password=password;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And I also needed to set sql server to allow mixed mode authentication. Now I seem to be able to hit the service without issues.. Hooray!

Comment: It seems your service cannot connect to the database from your other machine. Does this database reside on your development machine or is it only reachable from your development machine?

Comment: Can your MVC application, hosted in IIS, connect directly to the database? Does it work?

Comment: The service is making a call to a database that is on the same machine that IIS is on. It is all on my computer. I have not tested whether or not my MVC application can talk directly to the database, but I want it set up so my MVC application does not know anything about the database or the business logic taking place. That is all happening in the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your WCF app, and is most likely a config related.  To fix this, I would recommend that you attach debugger to your WCF hosted in IIS and debug the  GetUserRecord method.

Here are some tips for how to debug WCF service hosted in IIS

[Debug WCF service hosted in local IIS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876065/debug-wcf-service-hosted-in-local-iis-not-working)

[debugging asp.net WCF service hosted in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809865/debugging-asp-net-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis/15813759#15813759)

What I suspect is that you are using windows auth in your connection string, and the user owning the app pool does not have access to the Database. If your debugging reveals that that's the case, I would recommend that you assign DB rights to apppool user or change the connection string to use SQL authentication

Now for the connection string error, I would recommend that you go through the following blog entry.

http://failuresincoding.blogspot.com/2011/12/entity-framework-provider-did-not.html

Also, Do you have multiple SQL Servers on the local box? I would recommend that you use the complete instance name instead of "."

Comment: AH, you were correct. I attached to the IIS process and found the login failed stuff. I just need to figure out how to modify the permission on the db to allow the defaultapppool user to be able to hit the db, right?

Comment: Or, use the SQL authentication in your connection string to test.

Comment: Ok so I changed my conn string to look like this: <add name="MyLocalDB" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyLocalDB;User Id=LocalSQLUser;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> and it is still saying the login failed, provider did not return manifest token. Is the conn string wrong?

Comment: provide the full name of SQL server instance. "Data Source=." will map to name of the machine. if that differs from the instance name, you will have issues.

Comment: '.' is what I use in sql server management service to log in. I don't specify an instance, and never have. If I specify ./SQLEXPRESS, the db I am looking for it not there, and if I try ./MSSQLSERVER it gives me an error.

Comment: Consider changing "." to the machine name. if that doesn't work, this is most likely a typo in your connection string. consider a different format from http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012#sqlconnection

Comment: turns out I did not have mixed mode auth set on sql, so the sql login was not working for that reason. You pointed my in the direction of the solution, so thank you!