# Debugging the self-hosted WCF service via Client through Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have created a client application to consume the hosted web service and was able to consume the service without any issues(WCF service self hosted under  microsoft services).
Now my aim is to debug the self hosted WCF service using the Visual studio client application.
When I try to debug,an exception is thrown at consuming point method that

*Unable to debug the remote application.The remote procedure couldnt be debugged.*

Note:I have attached the process(hosted service process) to the debugger which is running.Before installing the service,I was able to debug through client VS to server VS just for cross checking.Both client and server are in different projects.

My question is how can I debug the service since I cannot run the hosted application because both are consuming the same end point.I dont understand the whole debugging thing because to debug an application it must be run with code,but hosted application is independent of code.I have checked and tried to understand this debugging,I think I am missing something critical.

Comment: If they are separate processes(not in the same solution), I agree with Matt Davis' suggestion, we will not be able to "step into" it when debugging the client unless we add System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() or others here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307182/wcf-can-no-longer-step-into-a-service-thats-locally-hosted-why-not

Answer (score -1):

I think this can help you.You can open your iis express port by flowing this link

[iis express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

and debug your service in your visual studio an call service from everywhere

[image: you can find your port number here]
or
[image: iis express applications]

Comment: It explains about hosting in IIS.But my application service  is self hosted I.e hosted in services not in IIS

Comment: if you use wcf its host is iis.I describe how to find your port number and you should open it and enjoy

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari _"if you use wcf its host is iis"_ - incorrect